# Browser return empty response with golang when doing http.Get in rest API

Tags: go

Trying catch error when doing http.Get but if remote server has error like no answer, DNS name not resolved it returns empty response in browser. What a right for way doing that?

Example:

```
func GetStatus(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

resp,err := http.Get("https://goodsfdsfgle.com")
    if err != nil {
          fmt.Fprint(w,"Remote server ok !")
                 } else { 
                           fmt.Fprint(w,"Remote server error")
                         }

}

func handleRequests() {
        http.HandleFunc("/status", GetStatus)
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":10000",nil))
}


func main() {

    handleRequests()
}
```

And when open browser localhost:10000/status get :
localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

But if url ok , everything ok trying use defer , few kind of catch error. Not working. Give empty response

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error check in the `GetStatus` function is incorrect and you introduced a local variable that you are not using. Please fix the code as follows:

```
func GetStatus(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _, err := http.Get("https://goodsfdsfgle.com")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Remote server error")
    } else {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Remote server ok !")
    }
}
```

Try accessing the service locally using `curl localhost:10000/status`. You should receive one of the `Remote server...` messages.

You will need to make more adjustments to create a working HTTP service, but please try the above code just to make things working initially.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"log"
"net/http"
)

func GetStatus(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

_,err := http.Get("https://goodsfdsfgle.com")
if err != nil {
fmt.Fprint(w,"Remote server error")
} else {
fmt.Fprint(w,"Remote server ok!")
}
}

func handleRequests() {
http.HandleFunc("/status", GetStatus)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":10000",nil))
}


func main() {

handleRequests()
}
```

Comment: Please note that the error handling is wrong. It only shows `Remote server ok !` because the host in the GET request doesn't seem to exist. You would need to check for `err != nil` for the failure case. See my answer to this question.

Comment: yes a little mistake if `err != nil` means there is a error. I fixed that